# Rails devise reset password fails if user record contains invalid data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I have an existing application in production where we have added new mandatory fields to the user record. As a result, the forgot password function is failing. I believe the failure occurs in the following method in recoverable.rb

```
  # Update password saving the record and clearing token. Returns true if
  # the passwords are valid and the record was saved, false otherwise.
  def reset_password(new_password, new_password_confirmation)
    if new_password.present?
      self.password = new_password
      self.password_confirmation = new_password_confirmation
      save
    else
      errors.add(:password, :blank)
      false
    end
  end
```

The new attributes cannot be generated mechanically. Only the user himself will know the correct values. Does anyone know of a way to get around this problem?

The only idea that I've come up with so far is as follows:

- use a rake script to populate the new fields with values that I know would never occur in real life but would be accepted by the model validation rule
- when the user logs in, detect if the user record contains invalid data and force them to do an update. In the user edit form, I would use some javascript to change the bogus values to blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *custom validation context* to make sure the validations on these added fields are only run when a user edits their profile, but skipped when (for example) Devise saves the user record.

In the User model, add an `on:`-clause to these validations

```
validates_presence_of :recently_added_mandatory_field, on: :user_updates_profile
```

And in the appropriate controller action, add this validation context when calling `#valid?` or `#save`:

```
# Existing code uses `@user.valid?` -> change to:
if @user.valid?(:user_updates_profile)
  …

# Existing code uses `@user.save` -> change to:
if @user.save(context: :user_updates_profile)
  …
```

See here for a full description of validation contexts: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Comment: In my case, when the user himself updates his profile, the method I use is update, i.e. @user.update(user_params). I don't see anywhere that it shows how to specify a custom validation context for the update method.

Comment: Just replace `@user.update(user_params)` with two statements: `@user.assign_attributes(user_params); @user.save(context: :user_updates_profile)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.